# Gradient for transparent corners for a rectangle?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

```
linear-gradient(to bottom left, blue, rgba(255,255,255,0));
```

How do we create create 3 other gradients for the bottom right, top left, top right? I looked at the documentation of Mozilla but nothing there.

Its not really the same as I'm trying to set the corners to a transparent color not a solid one.

Comment: @Harry I think I solved it with a radial gradient, although im curious how this can be done with a linear one.

Comment: Did you mean something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/d5e2s2pu/2/)?

Comment: @Harry indeed thats it.

Comment: Oh! Setting background position did the trick I see.

Comment: @Harry I noticed that your solution works well but has a few bugs. It seems the browser implementation is not so good yet and radial gradient does somewhat a fine job

Comment: It seems there are 4 lines, as if its cut into pieces.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/testopia/d5e2s2pu/3/

Comment: Interesting, I don't see anything like that in the output (using Chrome) but I've seen these line like things in the past. Try changing `background-size` to `51% 51%`.

Comment: @Harry now it overlaps. I believe that css gradients arent suited for the job.

Comment: Is your container fixed width or responsive? This issue generally happens only when %es are used. (*Note:* I am removing some of the older comments to keep the discussion short).

Comment: Ok then I'll leave it there and ping you if I have a better solution. By the way I am reopening it because your problem now seems considerably different to the linked ones. If you want I'll post my solution as an answer but not sure if it helps you because of the aforementioned problem.

Comment: @Harry thanks, I will read it when im home : ).

Answer (score 2):

**Using Linear Gradients (pure CSS):**

One way to create a gradient such that the corners are transparent would be to split the container into 4 parts. Each part will be 50% the height and width of the parent and will house one of the 4 gradients. By giving them the appropriate `background-position`, we can get the required effect.

```css
div {
  background: linear-gradient(to top left, yellow, transparent 75%), linear-gradient(to bottom left, yellow, transparent 75%), linear-gradient(to top right, yellow, transparent 75%), linear-gradient(to bottom right, yellow, transparent 75%);
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-position: 0px 0%, 0px 100%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 20%;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

**Note:** As discussed in comments, it seems like browsers leave a small gap (white line) in the middle. This issue seems to happen when the calculated pixel width of the element is an odd number (that is `20%` equals an odd number). For example, assume that the calculated width is `125px`. At such time `background-size` in X-axis becomes `62px` (`50%` of `125px` is rounded down to the nearest integer). Because of this rounding down, the size of either half of the gradient is only 62px and this introduces a 1px gap in between the gradients (which is nothing but the white line).

It is much safer to use the pure CSS approach for fixed width containers as we can then directly give the `background-size` in pixels.

---

**Pure CSS Workaround:**

One possible workaround for this with pure CSS would be to set the `background-position` such that it starts at 1px from the left. The second `div` in the below snippet seems to be displaying fine and it is also responsive. The **drawback** is that there will be a small overlap in the middle. Depending on your needs, this overlap may or may not be desirable.

```css
div {
  background: linear-gradient(to top left, yellow, transparent 75%), linear-gradient(to bottom left, yellow, transparent 75%), linear-gradient(to top right, yellow, transparent 75%), linear-gradient(to bottom right, yellow, transparent 75%);
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-position: 0px 0%, 0px 100%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width:20%;
  height:60px;
}
div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: linear-gradient(to top left, yellow, transparent 75%), linear-gradient(to bottom left, yellow, transparent 75%), linear-gradient(to top right, yellow, transparent 75%), linear-gradient(to bottom right, yellow, transparent 75%);
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-position: 1px 0%, 1px 100%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%; /* position is altered */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width:20%;
  height:60px;
}

div:hover{
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<br/>
<div></div>
```

---

**Workaround with a bit of JavaScript:**

If usage of a bit of JavaScript is not a problem then this issue can be addressed easily. The only thing that should be done is set the `width` of the container element such that it is always an even number. This would mean that the calculated `background-size` will not have a rounding down and hence there will be no gap in between. The `width` should be set `onload`, `onresize` and on any other events that would result in a change of width (say `hover`).

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var width = document.querySelector('div:nth-of-type(1)').parentElement.clientWidth;
  var childWidth = Math.round(width / 5);
  childWidth = (childWidth % 2 == 1) ? childWidth - 1 : childWidth;
  document.querySelector('div:nth-of-type(1)').style.width = childWidth + 'px';
}
```

```css
div {
  background: linear-gradient(to top left, yellow, transparent 75%), linear-gradient(to bottom left, yellow, transparent 75%), linear-gradient(to top right, yellow, transparent 75%), linear-gradient(to bottom right, yellow, transparent 75%);
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-position: 0px 0%, 0px 100%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 20%;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55632092/476951) below for an enhancement

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it with cutting the background into 9 slices (3 by 3): A center one, 4 at the edges and 4 in the corners. The center one will get a single color gradient, the edge gradients will be linear and the corner gradients will be radial, like this

Each slice will get a different `background-image`, `background-size` and `background-position`, all having `background-repeat: no-repeat;`

```css
.gradient {
  -webkit-animation: shrink-grow 4s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
          animation: shrink-grow 4s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: 
    /* center */
    linear-gradient(to bottom, red 0%, red 100%), 
    /* top */
    linear-gradient(to top, red 70%, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, purple, transparent), 
    /* right */
    linear-gradient(to right, red 70%, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, purple, transparent), 
    /* bottom */
    linear-gradient(to bottom, red 70%, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, purple, transparent), 
    /* left */
    linear-gradient(to left, red 70%, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, purple, transparent), 
    /* top left */
    radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-side at 100% 100%, red 70%, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, purple, transparent), 
    /* top right */
    radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-side at 0 100%, red 70%, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, purple, transparent), 
    /* bottom right */
    radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-side at 0 0, red 70%, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, purple, transparent), 
    /* bottom left */
    radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-side at 100% 0, red 70%, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, purple, transparent);
  background-position: 
    /* center */
    50px 50px, 
    /* top */
    50px 0, 
    /* right */
    100% 50px, 
    /* bottom */
    50px 100%, 
    /* left */
    0 50px,
    /* top left */
    0 0, 
    /* top right */
    100% 0,
    /* bottom right */
    100% 100%, 
    /* bottom left */
    0 100%;
  background-size:
    /* center */
    calc(100% - 2 * 50px) calc(100% - 2 * 50px), 
    /* top */
    calc(100% - 2 * 50px) 50px, 
    /* right */
    50px calc(100% - 2 * 50px), 
    /* bottom */
    calc(100% - 2 * 50px) 50px, 
    /* left */
    50px calc(100% - 2 * 50px), 
    /* top left */
    50px 50px, 
    /* top right */
    50px 50px, 
    /* bottom right */
    50px 50px, 
    /* bottom left */
    50px 50px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@-webkit-keyframes shrink-grow {
  0%, 100% {
    width: 350px;
    height: 200px;
  }
  25% {
    width: 450px;
    height: 200px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 450px;
    height: 100px;
  }
  75% {
    width: 350px;
    height: 100px;
  }
}

@keyframes shrink-grow {
  0%, 100% {
    width: 350px;
    height: 200px;
  }
  25% {
    width: 450px;
    height: 200px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 450px;
    height: 100px;
  }
  75% {
    width: 350px;
    height: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient"></div>
```

I made an SCSS mixin, you can see [in action here](https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/wZdpPb?editors=1100)

```css
@mixin rectangular-gradient($center-color, $gradient, $edge: 1em) {

  background-image:
    linear-gradient(to bottom, #{$center-color} 0%, #{$center-color} 100%),
    linear-gradient(to top, #{$gradient}),
    linear-gradient(to right, #{$gradient}),
    linear-gradient(to bottom, #{$gradient}),
    linear-gradient(to left, #{$gradient}),
    radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-side at 100% 100%, #{$gradient}),
    radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-side at 0 100%, #{$gradient}),
    radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-side at 0 0, #{$gradient}),
    radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-side at 100% 0, #{$gradient}),
  ;
  background-position:
    $edge $edge,
    $edge 0,
    100% $edge,
    $edge 100%,
    0 $edge,
    0 0,
    100% 0,
    100% 100%,
    0 100%,
    ;
  background-size: 
    calc(100% - 2 * #{$edge}) calc(100% - 2 * #{$edge}),
    calc(100% - 2 * #{$edge}) $edge,
    $edge calc(100% - 2 * #{$edge}),
    calc(100% - 2 * #{$edge}) $edge,
    $edge calc(100% - 2 * #{$edge}),
    $edge $edge,
    $edge $edge,
    $edge $edge,
    $edge $edge,
  ;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From documentation example `linear-gradient( 45deg, blue, red );`. So you just have to change `45deg` to desired angle. To have multiple gradients for single element, just separate them with comma.

```
linear-gradient(), linear-gradient()
```

Comment: What OP wants is multiple gradients in background, what you're explaning is the same as what OP does now.

Comment: @KeesSonnema yep I agree.

Comment: So three times linear gradient?

Comment: @Asperger Yes, 3 times.

Comment: I did seperate those with comma

Comment: @Asperger It's because your second gradient will overlap first one. Try using ` rgba(0,0,255,.5),  rgba(255,0,0,.5)` (opacity sum is 1).

Comment: @Justinas  tried that before. I set the second colors to transparent but the entire thing overlaps. Im trying to have all 3 corners transparent but, the issue is that as soon as I change the degrees of other gradients then the non transparent part overlaps with the transparent area of the other gradients

Comment: @Asperger Can't you just use `border-radius`?

Comment: @Justinas https://jsfiddle.net/testopia/d5e2s2pu/1/ I think im close, what do you say?

Comment: I think it cant be achieved with linear gradient

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for the odd pixel count issue in [Harry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2606013/harry)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34765815/476951): Add half a pixel to the position and the size with `calc`

```css
div {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to top left, red, transparent 75%), 
    linear-gradient(to bottom left, red, transparent 75%), 
    linear-gradient(to top right, red, transparent 75%), 
    linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, transparent 75%);
  background-size: calc(50% + 0.5px) calc(50% + .5px);
  background-position: 
    0px 0%, 
    0px calc(100% + .5px), 
    calc(100% + .5px) 0%, 
    calc(100% + .5px) calc(100% + .5px);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 20%;
  height: 60px;
  
  animation: shrink-grow 10s infinite  linear;
}

@keyframes shrink-grow {
  0%, 100% {
    width: 200px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```